# Confusion in n-factor calculation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry, coordination-compounds, mole

How do we calculate the equivalent weight of a compound, in a case where certain fraction of an element of the compound is getting reduced, while the other fraction is unaffected (no change in oxidation state)? For example, consider the following reaction:

$$\ce{Zn + K4[Fe(CN)6] -> K2Zn3[Fe(CN)6]2 + K}$$

I would like to calculate the equivalent weight of potassium ferrocyanide, given its molecular weight $M$. Here *some* potassium gets reduced to oxidation state (0) from (I).

Comment: *"Here, some potassium gets reduced to oxidation state (0) from (I)"* That reaction equation **makes no sense whatsoever**. $\ce{K+}$ does not get reduced that way.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that reaction actually happens. The question is, how do we calculate the equivalent weight?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86309/calculating-n-factor-of-so2/86315#86315 is an answered question about calculating the equivalent weight in the case of redox reactions.

Comment: That particular link doesn't answer my question!

Comment: *"I'm sorry, but that reaction actually happens."* Please provide a *credible* reference.

Comment: The link shows how equivalent weights are arrived at. Apply the same principle to any redox reaction.

Comment: Had it answered my question, I'd not have asked it here again. Please try to understand that the general method is not applicable here as only a certain fraction of potassium atoms are reduced, not all!

Comment: Your reaction isn't even balanced. Please provide a reference for it. There no reducer strong enough in there to reduce $\ce{K+}$ to elemental K. The only reducing agent present is $\ce{Zn}$.

Comment: Also K isn't stable in contact with water. It will react to give $\ce{K ->[H2O]KOH + H2(g)}$

Comment: @MaxW: to be fair, he didn't specify aqueous medium.

Comment: The OS of $\ce{Fe}$ in that complex doesn't change. It's +III on both sides. Only $\ce{Zn}$ and (cough!!) $\ce{K+}$ does.

Comment: I found numerous sources which suggest the following reaction: $$\ce{3Zn^2+ + 2[K4Fe(CN)6] -> K2Zn3[Fe(CN)6]2 + 6K+}$$ which is also performed in aqueous media only. Sorry, no potassium metal among products, not by a chance.

Comment: @andselisk: yes, I saw these too. OP's refusal to provide a reference speaks volumes.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This should do your work:

**3**Zn + **2**K<sub>4</sub>[Fe(CN)<sub>6</sub>] = K<sub>2</sub>Zn<sub>3</sub>(Fe(CN)<sub>6</sub>)<sub>2</sub> + **6** K

Now you can calculate the n factor.

On a second thought Zn **may** be ionic with +2 Oxidation state releasing K+.

Comment: I don't understand why this got upvoted. All you've done is balance a non-existing reaction. We can all do *that!*

Comment: As I see, he wanted to solve some question and the exams many a times commit this mistake. So, it's better to ignore it.